# Counting number of vowels in a given string

Tags: java, string

I am creating a method in a class that counts the number of vowels in a string.  First, I created a method `isVowel()` that tested if a letter was a variable and returned a `boolean` value.  Then I used the `isVowel()` method to create the `countVowels()` method. However, the code I wrote for the `countVowels()` method doesn't seem to be working but my `isVowel()` method does work and returns a correct value when tested on a letter.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
public int countVowels() {
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (i < text.length()) {
        String letter = text.substring(i, i + 1); // the ith letter
        if (isVowel(letter) == true) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = counter + 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: as a side note, you don't have to include an `else` block if you don't need it.

Comment: What have you tried and the result? This code is not wrong

Comment: Perhaps you should post your `isVowel` method.

Comment: You say `isVowel` returns `true` when tested on "a letter".  But was that letter a vowel letter?  And does it also return `false` when tested on a consonant letter?

Comment: *"that tested if a letter was a variable"* How can a letter be a variable?

Comment: And also how do you define "not working"?  Blows up with an exception? Returns wrong count (too high, too low, always zero, always the length of the input string, apparently random values)?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly the problem is. However, a for loop would better suit the task at hand rather than a while loop.

i.e.

```
public int countVowels(){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        String letter = text.substring(i, i + 1);
        if(isVowel(letter))
           counter++;
    }
    return counter; 
}
```

then your `isVowel` method should be something along the lines of:

```
public boolean isVowel(String c){
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    return vowels.contains(c);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why the for loop is better?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen `for` loop is better because it is more concise, because it keep the loop logic together, and because it limits the scope of the iteration variable (`i`) to within the loop.

Comment: my teacher specifically wants a while loop and yes my isVowel() is along those lines and returns correct true or false values.

Comment: @user8346999 you are not specifying what error are you getting. Assuming your  `isVowel ` method is working, there is nothing wrong with your code (it's not perfect but functionally, it should work)